# sql%bulk_exception implementation in db2

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, db2, database-migration

Basically i am trying to convert stored procedures written in oracle to DB2.
I have referred lot of sites and tried lot of migration tools like ibm dcw, sqllines, etc.
I am stuck in converting implementation of sql%bulk_exception in db2.
The code looks like:

```
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
    l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
    ROLLBACK;
    FOR i IN 1..l_error_count
    LOOP
      l_error_index := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX;
      l_error_code := SUBSTR(SQLERRM(SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE),1,200);
      <<inserting error codes ,error index into another table>>

    END LOOP;
```

Could you please help provide some sample approach to handle such in db2.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You catch bulk exception while doing `BULK COLLECT` operation in Oracle. `BULK COLLECT` is part of the Oracle compatibility feature in DB2, so, firstly, you cannot use it in the DB2 SQL PL native context. So why do are you trying to implement a feature that you cannot se it at first place in Db2

Comment: Sorry, i missed to mention that i have enabled oracle compatibility. Is it possible to implement this with PL/SQL either.

I heard about continue handler, but not able to implement in a procedure which is in a package.

Could someone help me in recording sql exception codes and inserting into a table by continue handler implementation.